# How can I work with filenames in Idea http editor by relative path or using env variables?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea http-editor I need to use json files as json bodies by relative path (or even with env variables in their names)

I have tried several variants but nothing works and I have to write absolute path to json files anyway.

I need something like this:

```
POST {{host-metadata}}/entities/{{model}}{{model-version}}/Organization/identifiers
Content-Type: application/json

< \rest\resources\json-bodies\identifiers\definitions\NameWithoutOpf.json
###
```

or that:

```
POST {{host-metadata}}/entities/{{model}}{{model-version}}/Organization/identifiers
Content-Type: application/json

< {{path-to-project}}\rest\resources\json-bodies\identifiers\definitions\NameWithoutOpf.json
###
```

in order to keep these requests in repo for example and to use it by team but have to write like this:

```
POST {{host-metadata}}/entities/{{model}}{{model-version}}/Organization/identifiers
Content-Type: application/json

< C:\MyFolder\MyProject\rest\resources\json-bodies\identifiers\definitions\NameWithoutOpf.json
###
```

I can't find enough info about syntax for this editor. Can someone tell me please?

Comment: Not yet possible, unfortunately: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43961
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-37987

Comment: Thank you! Found a way to address relative paths via comments there for files in requests for new HTTP editor - its already good step even without params in path for files.